# Python list comprehension returning a shorter list than it started with

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a column in a dataframe that is supposed to be all numeric characters, but in some cases there are some alphabetic characters mixed in. I am trying to use a list comprehension to get rid of the non-numeric characters so that I have a list that I can then convert to a Series and write over the old values.

My specific problem is that the resulting list is only about half the length of the original dataframe column that is being used in the comprehension. Why is this happening?

```
if df.CEEB.dtype=='object':
    CEEBcomp = {re.sub("[^0-9]","",str(x)) for x in list(df.CEEB)}
```

Answer (score 8):

You didn't create a list. You created a *set*, which can only hold unique elements. You must've had quite few duplicates for the result to be half the length.

A list comprehension would use square brackets:

```
CEEBcomp = [re.sub("[^0-9]", "", str(x)) for x in df.CEEB]
```

You don't need to use `list()` on `df.CEEB`; it must be an iterable for `list()` to work and an iterable is all you need for a comprehension, set or list or otherwise.